# Magento - 2.2.6 Possible Problems?

Tags: discussion, magento2.2.6

Magento released Magento-2.2.6 version on 18th Sep 2018.

**This release includes:**

1. 25 critical enhancements to product security, over 150 core code fixes and enhancements, and over 350 community-submitted pull requests.
2. Although this release includes these security enhancements, no confirmed attacks related to these issues have occurred to date.
3. However, certain vulnerabilities can potentially be exploited to access customer information or take over administrator sessions, so we recommend that you upgrade your Magento software to the latest version as soon as possible.

The Magento is recommending upgrading our Magento software to the latest version ASAP.

**What are the Possible Issues with this Magento-2.2.6 release?**

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom attributes and use those attributes to create widget rules, most of the widgets I used, caused errors and had to be removed.

In my case, it seemed that some of the attributes being called were having errors with 'back-ticks' replacing single quotes ' with back-ticks when rendering the page.

I deleted the widgets using those attributes and the page loads without issue.

I also need to re-write some of the cart and catalog rules as well, again, due to the back-tick issue.

**1 major issue** I am having,

"*Remove pub/media/catalog/product/cache . (Removing this folder frees up space.) & Run bin/magento catalog:image:resize to generate a new image cache. (This step is necessary because we’ve changed the path to cached images and must remove the previously cached images.)*"

Removing the 'pub/media/catalog/product/cache' isn't a problem, but the 'bin/magento catalog:image:resize' is just creating new images inside of the folder I just removed. It said there would be a new path, but that doesn't seem to be the case so far, unless I'm missing something. But do plan on the image resize to take a LONG time. 22 minutes so far and less than 500 images processed.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered 2 problems regarding price reindexing. One problem is that configurable price indexer (and probably other complex products too but I have no production project who uses bundles and grouped products extensively) relies on its child product index to be properly executed. Configurable price indexer works in 2 step:

- build index data based on configurable product price which is null as magento does not allow you to set price on configurable price level
- update min and max columns in `catalog_product_index_price` table based on children data from the same table

The first bug I found was that `reindexList` method which is fired by scheduled reindex reindexed the given list by product type which was sorted based on ids provided. If the lowest id in the list was simple then all simples were reindexed before configurables, if it was configurable then configurables before simples.

The second bug relied on the fact that in the first step of the configurable price reindex proces table `catalog_product_index_price` was updated based on a query which created `where` part as `where e.entity_id BEETWEEN ? and ?` and values where min and max ids from the provided list. This resulted in index table being updated for all configurables form the range based on its data and in most cases all price column were set to 0. In the second step, where indexer should update min and max price based on children query was executed with `where` part like `where le.entity_id IN (?)`, so only for the configurables provided to the `reindexList` method making all other in the base state.